# Data Search in SQL database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to create a Invoice from my database. The database is having around 500 tables.

I am unaware of where actually the data resides in the database. I tried it with search data procedure, executing stored procedure.

Please let me know how could I get that now. My client is not a technical guy so don't have any information except that he has a database.

What I have is the software through which they are inserting their data into database.
but as by naming conventions in front end form, I am not able to get that.

Is there any way out to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use sql server profiler to check the statements generated to store the data and work from there

if the db is only used for that program you should be able to get the info quickly
if not find out the db user this program is using and set that as a filter...

Comment: Does it tell where my data actually flows from front-end to back-end(which table)

Comment: it will give you all the sql statements that are going to the db so you should see insert xxx into tblxxx or exec spxxx

Comment: if they already have something that creates an invoice you could try that 2, profiler will then show you the statments used to get the data

Comment: Thanks, It gives me lot of idea.